# Sql schema error on create table

Tags: sql, oracle

it generates an error,i cant understand whats wrong with the script..every suggestion would be helpful thnx

```
CREATE TABLE ar_abonent
(
    ar_nr_klienti_primary_key int,
    emri varchar(25),
    mbiemri varchar(25)
);

create table ar_celular
(
    NR_CEL INT (12),
    ar_nr_klienti FOREIGN Key REFERENCES ar_abonent (ar_nr_klienti),int,
    identifikues boolean,
    data_aktivizimit date,
    marka varchar(25)
    constraint chk_celular check (NR_CEL IN ('35566%','35567%','35568%','35569%' AND IDENTIFIKUES='TRUE')
);
```

Comment: the first table was sucsessfully created,i have issues with the second one.thank you

Comment: What error does it generate?

Comment: 1. Post the actual Error. 2. Add a tag for the version of SQL

Comment: ar_nr_klienti FOREIGN Key REFERENCES ar_abonent (ar_nr_klienti),int remove the comma before int

Comment: Error starting at line : 8 in command -
create table ar_celular
(
NR_CEL INT (12),
ar_nr_klienti FOREIGN Key REFERENCES ar_abonent (ar_nr_klienti),int,
identifikues boolean,
data_aktivizimit date,
marka varchar(25),
constraint chk_celular check (NR_CEL IN ('35566%','35567%','35568%','35569%' AND IDENTIFIKUES='TRUE')
)
Error at Command Line : 10 Column : 12
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: The line with `ar_nr_klienti` looks out-of-order to me.  You probably want the `int` declaration before the `foreign key` part.  And there should not be a `,` between them.

Comment: @user3430929 I added an answer with a script that does run as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE ar_abonent
(
    ar_nr_klienti int NOT NULL primary key ,  --<-- This column needs to be a primary key
    emri varchar(25),
    mbiemri varchar(25)
);

create table ar_celular
(
    NR_CEL INT ,
    ar_nr_klienti int FOREIGN Key REFERENCES ar_abonent (ar_nr_klienti) ,
    identifikues bit,
    data_aktivizimit date,
    marka varchar(25),
    constraint chk_celular check (NR_CEL IN ('35566%','35567%','35568%','35569%') AND IDENTIFIKUES= 1)
);
```

Comment: i already changed the script to this ..still the same thing.thanks a lot though,appriciated

Comment: @M.Ali Turns out the Oracle syntax was a bit different than the MS SQL that I'm used to. I posted the correct version below.

Answer (score 0):

I tried correcting it using SQL Fiddle (set to Oracle 11G R2) as I don't own any Oracle servers. This is how it should look to run without issues:

```
CREATE TABLE ar_abonent
(
    ar_nr_klienti int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    emri VARCHAR2(25),
    mbiemri VARCHAR2(25)
);

CREATE TABLE ar_celular
(
  NR_CEL int,
  ar_nr_klienti int,
  identifikues number(1),
  data_aktivizimit date,
  marka VARCHAR2(25),
  CONSTRAINT fk_column FOREIGN KEY (ar_nr_klienti) REFERENCES ar_abonent  (ar_nr_klienti),
  CONSTRAINT chk_celular CHECK (NR_CEL IN ('35566%','35567%','35568%','35569%') AND IDENTIFIKUES= 1)
);
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0973)

Turns out Oracle doesn't have a BOOLEAN type (at table level, although it does exist in PL/SQL), and VARCHAR2 might be preferred to VARCHAR (unless nulls are a concern).

Comment: but i need the 'dentifikues to work as a flag..as a true/false thing